# Why does my Twitter account keep reappearing in System Preferences/Internet Accounts?

Tags: system-settings, notifications, twitter

I delete my Twitter account from "Internet Accounts".

Within 10 seconds the Twitter account reappears.

How can I get it to reset?

Companion problem is that my Twitter account shows up multiple times in Notification Center

[image: multiple accounts]

What I have tried:

- Revoke access in Twitter account
- recovery disk/resetpassword (reset ACL)
- did a Safe Boot
- changed account from standard to administrator

Comment: Did you try to Revoke access in your Twitter account ?

Comment: sure did. What I would like to do at this point is remove *all* "Internet Accounts" and re-enter the accounts. Creating a new "user account" on the Mac is not really an option.

Comment: It could be that you need to restore your users ACL's

Comment: did that - no change

Comment: sorry, I was not specific, I meant not the Disk Utility ACL repair, but the user account.

Comment: did that (recovery disk/resetpassword) - no change - did a Safe Boot and tried - no change - changed account from standard to administrator - no change